# Error connecting to sql server 2008 using tcp/ip

Tags: sql-server-2008, tcp

I have configured my system to connect to the SQL Server 2008, I am running under windows server 2008, and I made the following:-

1. Enable TCP/IPon my SQL Server.
2. Activate and enable  the 192.168.1.20 for the SQL Server.
3. Add two inbounds rules for the 1433 post on the firewall and the sqlserver.exe.

But when I tried to connect the database I got the following error:-

> The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.1.20, port 1433 has failed.
>   Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties,  check
>   that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP
>   connections to the port.".

When I typed the following:

```
telnet 192.168.1.20
```

it gave me

```
Connecting To 192.168.1.20...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23:
Connect failed
```

So what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the telnet command is wrong, try

```
telnet 192.168.1.20 1433
```

You didn't mention about outbound rules. You need to add the inbound + outbound rules on your machine (in the firewall) and on SqlServer machine.

Comment: telnet 192.168.1.20 1433 will also give "Connecting To 192.168.1.20...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433 : Connect failed"

Comment: Ok, but did you put also outbound rules?

Comment: yes,, i add two outbound rules, and i also disable the firewall. but still can not telnet on the 192.168.1.20 1433 ..Best regards

Comment: Check whether you can connect from the same machine: from sqlserver machine connect to sql server using IP (192.168.1.20) and not instance name.